# String in list to float

Tags: python, string, list, floating-point

I have a list called 'ft_List that looks like...

```
[['Fall2001', '22.00', '2000', '01', '01', '120.0', '', 'N'], 
[CgeCam2002', '20.00', '2000', '09', '04', '0.0', '1', ''],
['Fall2004', '18.50', '2001', '18', '01', '', '', 'Y']........
```

...how can I convert column 5 to floats? I tried

```
for i in ft_Rec:
    ms = i[5].split(',')
    float(ms)
```

but get

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or number

. I thought it was a string?
Is it because some fields are empty (' ')? I'd like to perform some calculations with this column

Comment: even without split i get the same error

Comment: note that `float(ms)` doesn't modify your list: you need `i[5] = float(ms)`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to split this input, it is already a list, just check for empty string:

```
for i in ft_Rec:
    if i[5]: print float(i[5])
```

To get the total:

```
total = sum( float(i[5]) for i in ft_Rec if i[5] )
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. It seems to print  all as floats but where do I put sum(i[5])? If its within the for loop, it says float() not iterable

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> ft_List = [['Fall2001', '22.00', '2000', '01', '01', '120.0', '', 'N'],
['CgeCam2002', '20.00', '2000', '09', '04', '0.0', '1', ''],
['Fall2004', '18.50', '2001', '18', '01', '', '', 'Y']]
>>> for i in ft_List:
        i[5] = float(i[5] or 0) # empty string logical ors to 0


>>> ft_List
[['Fall2001', '22.00', '2000', '01', '01', 120.0, '', 'N'], ['CgeCam2002', '20.00', '2000', '09', '04', 0.0, '1', ''], ['Fall2004', '18.50', '2001', '18', '01', 0.0, '', 'Y']]
```

The problem is:

```
>>> float('')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    float('')
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

This solution just uses that fact that empty built-in objects in Python evaluate as False

```
>>> '' or 0
0
```

Comment: I qualified your "empty objects in Python evaluate as False": this is true for built-in objects, but is not required from user classes (which by default even evaluate to True even when "empty"!).

Comment: @EOL thanks, I was originally going to go with that but thought it made it too complicated

Answer (score 0):

you may do like this:

```
>>> for row in ll:
...     f = float(row[5]) if row[5] else 0.
...     print f
... 
120.0
0.0
0.0
```

where `ll` is:

```
>>> ll = [['Fall2001', '22.00', '2000', '01', '01', '120.0', '', 'N'], 
         ['CgeCam2002', '20.00', '2000', '09', '04', '0.0', '1', ''], 
         ['Fall2004', '18.50', '2001', '18', '01', '', '', 'Y']]
```

I am printing `0.0` for empty strings `''`

Answer (score -1):

python doesnot accept empty strings as argument for floats.

```
    >>>float(' ')
    >>>ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: The question is "how can I convert column 5 to floats?"…